# Rebase button is disabled while trying to rebase child branch with parent

Tags: git, rebase, github-desktop

I have a branch named **Test-Parent**.

I have created **Test-Child** branch from **Test-Parent**.

I pulled the **Test-Parent** branch in my GitHub Desktop and created a file *TempFile.txt* and pushed.

I need to rebase the **Test-Child** branch with **Test-Parent**.

I pulled the **Test-Child** branch in GitHub Desktop.

Went to Branch-> Rebase Current Branch:

[image]

But the *Rebase* button is disabled and message is coming as This branch is up to date with Test-Child:

[image]

When I compare this branch with **Test-Parent**, Able to see the difference:

[image]

Can you please help me how can I rebase **Test-Child** with **Test-Parent** from GitHub Desktop?

Comment: Have you tried a rebase from the command line?

Comment: From command line Ivam able to rebase. Hut how can we do the same from GitHub Desktop?

Comment: Only other suggestion I have is to make sure your parent branch is up to date with your origin/parent branch. In bash run `gitk --all` to see the entire history and local/remote branch locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Your branch has no new commits on it yet. In this case you can simply merge `Test-Parent` into `Test-Child` with fast-forward. That should be possible in GH Desktop and has the same effect as the rebase you wished to do. In your last screenshot it is offering this option, but with "Create a merge commit" selected. I'm guessing if you click on the arrow you can select a different option like "Regular Merge" or something like "Fast-Forward Merge".

**What's going on?**

Most GUI tools do a basic rebase. For example, if you have `Test-Child` checked out, and you wish to rebase your branch onto `Test-Parent`, it's equivalent to the command:

```
git rebase Test-Parent
```

That will do a hard reset of your branch to `Test-Parent`, and then for each of the commits on your branch that aren't on `Test-Parent`, it will cherry-pick them one by one. If you don't have any new commits on your branch, then it only does the reset portion of the command.

In your scenario, conceptually, there's nothing to actually rebase when your branch is *only* behind and doesn't have *new* commits of its own yet, so I don't fault GH Desktop for not offering the option in this case. That being said, I'd probably prefer that it still allow it anyway, just because  that's how it works from the command line. Some people may blindly rebase their branch whether it needs it or not, just out of habit, and on a fresh branch with no new commits they would expect it to still update their branch even though nothing gets rewritten.

**Other ways to update your branch**

In your particular case, if you have a branch named `Test-Child` which was created from `Test-Parent`, and since then some new commits were added to `Test-Parent` and you have no new commits yet on `Test-Child`, there are multiple ways to update your currently checked out `Test-Child` branch, including:

1. Merge: `git merge Test-Parent --ff-only`
2. Reset: `git reset --hard Test-Parent`
3. Recreate: `git switch -C Test-Child Test-Parent`
4. Rebase: `git rebase Test-Parent`
5. there are others...

Note that as soon as your branch has *new* commits on it, then to update your branch you can only use #4, and with new commits the rebase option will become available in GH Desktop too. (Alternatively, you could update your branch with a regular merge without the `--ff-only` option.)